# How to Merge objects using $.extend() in jQuery with all unique values

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I am trying to merge three objects in one new object, but it is overriding repeating values, can anyone help me out how to merge all object in one different object without changing in existing objects and containing all unique values.

```
var object1 = {
  red: 0,
  blue: { lightblue: 24, darkblue: 12 },
  black: 17
};
var object2 = {
  white: 200,
  blue: { lightblue: 40 }
};
var object3 ={
  yellow: 234
};

var targetresult = $.extend({}, object1, object2, object3);
console.log(targetresult);
```

Comment: Maybe use `Object.assign(to, from)` ?

Comment: i tried this one also but it is also overloading second object values and removing duplicate object

Comment: then try `$.merge(arr1, arr2)`

Comment: or `array1.concat(array2, array3, ..., arrayX)`

Comment: Give us an example of expected output. without it, it is unclear what exactly you expect the output to be.

Comment: dear sir i am talking about object, but you are replying about array @EvgenyKolyakov

Comment: Then $.extend() should work... hmmm

Comment: @KevinB hello sir,
please run my code and check currect result in console and add this line
$.extend(true, object1, object2, object3);
 console.log(targetresult,object1);
 and compare both console, you will see difference in value of blue:object value

Comment: @EvgenyKolyakov that is what i have written in code which is not giving expected result as it is produced by 
$.extend(true, object1, object2, object3);
 console.log(targetresult,object1);
 this console

Comment: @abhijeetgupta so what you're saying is, object1 is your target output? that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @KevinB no sir object1 is not my target output, i want output in new object but same as there is in object1

Comment: Then provide us with a sample output that you would expect.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're using the wrong data structure for this problem. Objects in JavaScript are supposed to have unique names for all their properties. That's why when you merge two objects, properties with the same name are overwritten.

For this situation, I recommend using an array as the main data structure. You can keep adding elements to the array without overwriting elements. You can then combine the arrays with the Array#concat method.

```
var array1 = 
[
{red: 0},
{blue: { lightblue: 24, darkblue: 12 }},
{black: 17}
];

var array2 = 
[
{white: 200},
{blue: { lightblue: 40 }}
];

var array3 =
[
{yellow: 234}
];

var targetResult = array1.concat(array2, array3);
console.log(targetResult);
```

In the code above, I made every element a `{name: value}` object. It's also acceptable to use `[name, value]` arrays as the array elements.

Comment: no sir if i am using like
'
var object1 = {
 red: 0,
 blue: { lightblue: 24, darkblue: 12 },
 black: 17
 };
 var object2 = {
 white: 200,
 blue: { lightblue: 40 }
 };
$.extend(true, object1, object2);
 console.log(object1);
'
 then it is giving perfect result, it is containing both values of blue object: lightblue and darkblue, but overriding the value lightblue, as because it is also in object2, i am just looking for solution to assign merged object to new one with no change in existing objects

Comment: What you are asking for is not possible. You cannot have multiple properties on an object with the same property name. Perhaps you want to rename the property when it already exists, to avoid overwriting the property when adding it to the combined object?

Comment: sir i want to keep all property of object but if there is any overriding property then it should override with recent one